# Erro ao solicitar POST (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI) - React/Node

Tags: node.js, react, hospedagem, cpanel

Estou tentando realizar um login com react e node, ao rodar localmente em meu computador ele funciona perfeitamente, quando eu subo no servidor hospedado ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

Obs.: A hospedagem é realizada na Hostgator e uso o Cpanel como gerenciador;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código do arquivo login.jsx do frontend

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import "./login.scss";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const Auth = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      history.push("/dashboard");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="all-login">
      <main className="container-login">
        <h2 className="subtitle-login">UniControl</h2>
        <form onSubmit={Auth} className="form-login">
          <div className="input-field-login">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Digite seu E-mail"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="underline-login"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field-login">
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Digite sua Senha"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="underline-login"></div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" position="right center" />
          {msg ? <p className="error-login">{msg}</p> : null}
        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Segue código do routes do backend;

```
import express from "express";
import { getUsers, Register, Login, Logout } from "../controllers/Users.js";
import { verifyToken } from "../middleware/VerifyToken.js";
import { refreshToken } from "../controllers/RefreshToken.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/users", verifyToken, getUsers);
router.post("/users", Register);
router.post("/login", Login);
router.get("/token", refreshToken);
router.delete("/logout", Logout);

export default router;
```

Segue código do index.js do backend

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import db from "./config/Database.js";
import router from "./routes/index.js";
dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server running at port 5000"));
```

Comment: Cara, acho que tu esqueceste de postar a mensagem de erro...

Comment: Esta na imagem abaixo da observação um print do console, NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI  e ele aponta para o login.jsx - obs.: sou iniciante em node.

Answer (score -1):

Eu arriscaria em dizer que o erro ocorre pelo simples fato de você estar tentando chamar a API através do `"localhost:5000"` e por isso o erro aponta um `BAD URI`.

Tente trocar esse `localhost:5000` para a URL que o usuário está. Localhost é para ser usado em ambiente local, mas em produção, isso não parece ser legal.

Imagine o seguinte cenário, localhost funciona para você, pois o site está hospedado no seu computador, mas para o usuário que está usando o site, no `localhost:5000` dele não tem absolutamente nada, então não tem como essa URI funcionar para ele.

Se eu não estiver enganado, se você simplesmente trocar

```
await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
```

para

```
await axios.post("/login", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
```

Ja deve funcionar, e faça o mesmo para todas as partes do código que estiverem usando "localhost" ao solicitar requisição da API.